# Saving updated ArrayList doesn't work

Tags: java, serialization, servlets, save

i've got the following problem:

I'm saving an ArrayList as a .ser file. If the file doesn't exist it gets created on load instead of throwing an exception.

Then i want to add something to the ArrayList and save it again. But when i open the ArrayList, it is empty. Where is the mistake?

When i throw out the ArrayList bevor the huge comment in the servlet, everything is working fine so it is possible to create an empty arraylist and add the object with alle the information.
But the saving of this updated ArrayList seems to be the problem.

I don't know where exactly the Problem is or why that happens. I think arround the huge comment in the Servlet. Here:

```
ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> auftraege = new ArrayList();
Lieferinhalte l = new Lieferinhalte();
l.setID(id);
l.setVon(start);
l.setNach(end);
l.setMail(mail);
l.setLink(link);


open o = new open();
auftraege = o.getAuftraege();
auftraege.add(l);

/*-----------> PROBLEM<-------------*/

File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Christoph\\workspace\\ServletTest\\auftraege.ser");

speichern s = new speichern();
s.abspeichern(auftraege);

open o2 = new open();
auftraege = o2.getAuftraege();

out.println(docType + "<HTML>\n"+
        "<HEAD><TITLE>HalloWelt</TITLE></HEAD>\n"+
        "<BODY>" + 
        "Servlet funktioniert! <br /><br />");
```

Here is the rest of the code for understanding:

Servlet, the Strings at the beginning get their information from a jsp-file which loads this servlet.

```
package servlet;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{   
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String id = request.getParameter("ID");
    String start = request.getParameter("Start");
    String end = request.getParameter("End");
    String mail = request.getParameter("Mail");
    String link = request.getParameter("Link"); 
    String docType =
            "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 "+
            "Transitional//EN\">\n";

    ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> auftraege = new ArrayList();
    Lieferinhalte l = new Lieferinhalte();
    l.setID(id);
    l.setVon(start);
    l.setNach(end);
    l.setMail(mail);
    l.setLink(link);


    open o = new open();
    auftraege = o.getAuftraege();
    auftraege.add(l);

    /*-----------> PROBLEM<-------------*/

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Christoph\\workspace\\ServletTest\\auftraege.ser");

    speichern s = new speichern();
    s.abspeichern(auftraege);

    open o2 = new open();
    auftraege = o2.getAuftraege();

    out.println(docType + "<HTML>\n"+
            "<HEAD><TITLE>HalloWelt</TITLE></HEAD>\n"+
            "<BODY>" + 
            "Servlet funktioniert! <br /><br />");

    for(int i = 0; i < auftraege.size(); i++) {
        String id2 = auftraege.get(i).ID;
        String start2 = auftraege.get(i).von;
        String end2 = auftraege.get(i).nach;
        String mail2 = auftraege.get(i).mail;
        String link2 = auftraege.get(i).link;

         out.println("Die ID war: " + id2 + "<br />" +
                "Der Startpunkt war: " + start2 + "<br />" +
                "Der Endpunkt war: " + end2 + "<br />" + 
                "Die Mail war: " + mail2 + "<br />" + 
                "Der Link war: " + link2 + "<br />");
    }

    out.println("<a href='index.jsp'>Hier</a> geht es zur&uuml;ck zur Eingabemaske!" +
            "</BODY></HTML>");

}
}
```

the saving class:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class speichern {

public void abspeichern(ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> a) {


     OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try
        {
            // Byteorientierten Ausgabekanal Öffnen
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream("auftraege.ser");

            // Objektausgabekanal für Serialisierung Öffnen
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

            // Objekte serialisiert in Datei ausgeben
            objectOutput.writeObject(a);


            // Ausgabekanal schließen
            objectOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}

}
```

The load class:

package servlet;

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class open {

ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> a;

open() {

    try
    {
        // Serialisiertes Objekt
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("auftraege.ser");
        // Deserialisierung
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        // String auslesen
        this.a = (ArrayList<Lieferinhalte>) objectInput.readObject();



    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        speichern s = new speichern();
        ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> auftraege = new ArrayList();
        s.abspeichern(auftraege);

        open o = new open();
        this.a = o.a;


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
       speichern s = new speichern();
       ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> auftraege = new ArrayList();
       s.abspeichern(auftraege);

       open o = new open();
       this.a = o.a;
    }

}

ArrayList<Lieferinhalte> getAuftraege(){
    return a;
}


}
```

and the class for the object which should be saved in the arraylist:

```
package servlet;

public class Lieferinhalte {

String link = "";
String ID ="";
String von ="";
String nach ="";
String mail ="";

void setLink(String a) {
    this.link = a;
}

void setID(String a) {
    this.ID= a;
}

void setVon(String a) {
    this.von = a;
}

void setNach(String a) {
    this.nach = a;
}

void setMail(String a) {
    this.mail = a;
}
}
```

Comment: Rather than saying "I don't know where the problem is," please try to pinpoint your issue at least a little bit; remember, [StackOverflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/104200).

Comment: The problem is, as i said, i think in the servlet at the huge comment line.

When i use the ArrayList before the comment everythink is working. When i use the ArrayList after the comment, it doesn't work. so i think the prolem ist there.

Comment: Post the exact stack trace and Exception that's being thrown

Comment: Rather than pointing your finger at one line in 200 where you think the problem is, reduce the problem to 20 lines.

Comment: There isn't an exception thrown except the planed exception for creating the .ser file.

The problem is that the ArrayList after the huge comment in the servlet is empty.

i Updated the post with a code fragment where i think the problem is.

Comment: The longest comment in your code is `// Objektausgabekanal für Serialisierung Öffnen` -- I wouldn't call it "huge" :)

Comment: "open o2 = new open(); 
    auftraege = o2.getAuftraege();" You're setting auftraege to o2's arraylist which is empty. Surely you need to deep copy the elements across, not assign it to the other empty arraylist? Ahh, I may have been mistaken as to what open does. But this does seem to me to be where the cause might be.

Comment: Oh sorry, i mean this comment: /*-----------> PROBLEM<-------------*/

Have a look at the firstcode fragment :)

Comment: @PerryMonschau `this.a = (ArrayList<Lieferinhalte>) objectInput.readObject();`

Comment: You're doing some pretty crazy stuff in you exception handlers in the `open()` constructor -- that could lead to infinite recursion. If it fails, you retry -- what are the odds of it suddenly NOT failing? There are many reasons besides that the file doesn't exist yet. This is very fragile.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? I can't help beyond guessing in the dark.

Comment: @Perry Monschau
Why is o2's ArrayList empty? I think it loads the ser-File which s saves.

Comment: This line is a no-op, you might as well delete it: `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Christoph\\workspace\\ServletTest\\auftraege.ser");`

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: i think the only Exception that could really happen is, if the ser File should be loaded and doesn't exist. When it doesn't exist it is created and everything should work, or am i wrong?

Yeah and i saw this line seconds ago. You are right with this!

Comment: There are many reasons why it could fail. This is definitely not something you should put in production code. Check explicitly for file existence, the exception could come from that or from a million other reasons the server code may encounter.

Comment: The file defenetly exists. If i delete it it gets created again : /

Comment: Lieferinhalte doesn't implement `Serializable`. How do you imagine this could work?

Comment: I think it should work because im saving the ArrayList and not directly the Lieferinhalte.

You think if i implement Serializable it could work?

Comment: Currently all I know is that if you don't implement `Serializable`, there's nothing further to discuss. Whether that's the only problem you have is to be seen.

Comment: I tried that and it works!

thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare your Lieferinhalte  class as serializable (implements Serializable)!

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
implements Serializable
```

than it should work.